# parsing exception on numbers

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to index data that look like the following :

```
var json = {
    "kwg": {
        "kwg0List": [
            {
                "lemma": "bilingue",
                "categories": [
                    "terme"
                ],
                "occList": [
                    {
                        "startTimeSec": 537.1,
                        "endTimeSec": 537.46,
                        "value": "bilingue"
                    },
                    {
                        "startTimeSec": 563.2,
                        "endTimeSec": 563.55,
                        "value": "bilingue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. Now, let's say, for whatever reason, that the one of the `startTimeSec` fields is equal to `10`. It's interpreted as a `long` and not as a `double` anymore.

I would get the following error : `mapper_parsing_exception`, telling me that I should have a `double` and not a `long`.

Now my question is : is there a way to "force" the `long` to be cast to a `double` when indexing, or is previously checking that the data is correctly formatted the only way of doing it?

Trace :

```
{
    "took": 1112,
    "errors": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "create": {
          "_index": "library",
          "_type": "relevance",
          "_id": "AViRhRJ-_Tb2laJ1W4JH",
          "status": 400,
          "error": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "mapper [kwg.kwg0List.occList.endTimeSec] of different type, current_type [double], merged_type [long]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Weird, usually it's the other way around that fails, i.e. having a long mapping type and sending doubles. Do you mind sharing the exact stack trace you see in the ES log?

Comment: I added the trace above. I managed to fix it creating a mapping. It's weird though because I thought it would automatically set the field type to double (unless the first field of the document is a long, which I am going to check)

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15377) about this. Also see [this one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15961)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a look !